# For how long can I access my DB and Web API hosted in Azure

Tags: azure

I need to host my MSSql DB, Web APi and another Web application on Azure. I'd like to sign up for a free account. I looked into the the FAQs section there but didn't quite understand what can I and can not use after my trial period expires. So, the question is: **Am I gonna be able to use my services and DB after my trial period expires?**. What is free after the expiration period? As I understand, pretty much nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a billing/service-offer question. Not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

The fee depends on the tier you choose during the creation of those services. You can check the tier in the portal for each of those resources separately.
After the trial ends, you won't be able to access said resources (well, unless you pay from them, but that's no longer a trial in that case.).